# Javascript - How to check if a string contains multiple substrings

Tags: javascript, substring

I have multiple sub-strings that I want to find in a single string and if all three are found then do this, if not, do something else.

I am kind of stuck on how to set it so that if I get three "True", I want to execute something, other I want it to do something else.

Many thanks.

My code is below.

```js
//Main String
var string0 = ' ": {"MATHEMATICS": {"status": "start", "can_start": false}, "READING": {"status": "start", "can_start": false}, "WRITING": {"status": "start", "can_start": false" ';

//Substrings
var substringArray = ['"MATHEMATICS": {"status": "start"', '"READING": {"status": "start"', '"WRITING": {"status": "start"'];

//Check if Substrings are found in MainString
for (l = 0; l < substringArray.length; l++) {
  if (string0.indexOf(substringArray[l]) > -1) {
    logger.info("True");
  } else {
    logger.info("False");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a variable to count the number of "true"

```js
  //Main String
  var string0 = ' ": {"MATHEMATICS": {"status": "start", "can_start": false}, "READING": {"status": "start", "can_start": false}, "WRITING": {"status": "start", "can_start": false" ';

  //Substrings
  var substringArray = ['"MATHEMATICS": {"status": "start"', '"READING": {"status": "start"', '"WRITING": {"status": "start"'];

  var matchCount = 0;

  //Check if Substrings are found in MainString
  for (l = 0; l < substringArray.length; l++) {
    if (string0.indexOf(substringArray[l]) > -1) {
     logger.info("True");
     matchCount++;
    } else {
      logger.info("False");
    }
  }

  if(matchCount == 3){
      //do something
      logger.info('I did');
  } else {
      // do some other thing
      logger.info('I did not');
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, we posted at the same time! I have marked yours as the answer. Thank you :)

Comment: use substringArray.length instead of hard coded 3, then it will work for any number of elements in substringArray

Answer (score 4):

You can try use [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method to check for all the substrings.

An example of code:

```
var isContainsAllTheParts = substringArray.every(function(substring){
    return string0.indexOf(substring) >= 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it.

```js
var magicNumber = 0;

//Check if Substrings are found in string0
for (l = 0; l < substringArray.length; l++) {
  //logger.info(substringArray[l]);
  if (string0.indexOf(substringArray[l]) > -1) {
    logger.info("True");
    magicNumber++;
  } else {
    logger.info("False");
  }
}

while (magicNumber < 3) {
  //execute this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Telman Ahababov's answer wasn't accepted.
I'll explain it in case it wasn't clear enough. I'm also shortening it up a bit more and using the simpler includes() method:

```
let str = "Here is the string in which we want to find multiple substrings."

let subStrArr = ["Here is", "which we", "multiple"]

let containsAllSubStrs = subStrArr.every(subStr => {
        return str.includes(subStr);
    });

if (containsAllSubStrs) {
        //containsAllSubStrs equals 'true', meaning all substrings were found.
} else {
        //containsAllSubStrs equals 'false', meaning NOT all substrings were found.
    }
```